# Serveroutput from a TSQL procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a message on the console in the SQL Server Management Studio with a TSQL procedure. Basically the same thing as

```
set serveroutput on
dbms_output.put_line ('hello');
```

does in Oracle. Hows can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Print..

```
Print 'Hello world'
```

For variabless..

```
print @a
```